# Rudimentary results in iterated forcing.

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, forcing

What are some relatively basic and fun results using iterated forcing that I can include in my undergraduate thesis in the section I'm going to title "Rudimentary applications." It's the section following the section titled "Fundamental Theorems of Iterated Forcing."

Eventually, in some other section, I'm going to include the result by Dow, Tall, and Weiss on the consistency of the [Normal Moore Space conjecture,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(topology)) which is obtained by an iteration of cohen forcing of supercompact length.

Comment: It depends what you call basic. You can control the exponential function on regular cardinals (Easton). If this seems too involved, you can do it for countably many consecutive cardinals without much effort. There is the consistency of Martin's axiom. Many of the consistency results regarding the Cichon diagram.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Perhaps basic can be taken to mean around the difficulty of consitency of MA (which I've seen somewhat). These results on Chichon diagram I find very beautiful and interesting. Do you happen to know off the top of your head which of them use an infinite iteration?  (Or some recommended bibliography.)

Comment: I would suggest reading Blass's chapter in the Handbook of set theory and some of the Bartoszynski-Judah book for inequalities among classical cardinal characteristics, together with Baumgartner's paper on iterated forcing. The reason for the latter is that many of these arguments require understanding of countable support iterations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proof of the consistency of [ZFC+$\neg$CH+MA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_axiom) uses an iterated forcing argument; I wouldn't necessarily call it "rudimentary," but it's definitely simpler than the consistency of the normal Moore space conjecture.

A simpler result, which is however of less general interest in my opinion, is the consistency relative to ZFC of ZFC+"There are exactly three degrees of constructibility of real numbers." The proof is a two-step iteration of Sacks forcing over a model of ZFC+V=L: the first step produces a unique nonzero constructibility degree of a real, and the second step produces a unique nonzero constructibility degree of a real above the first one. This is a nice case where we see vividly the difference between the product and the support, since the product $\mathbb{S}\times\mathbb{S}$ of two Sacks forcings over $L$ yields *four* degrees of constructibility of reals: the trivial one, the left generic, the right generic, and their join. *(A nice coda to this is the observation that the crucial property is that the Sacks forcing of a generic extension is not the same as the Sacks forcing of the ground model.)*

Finally, there are [cardinal characteristic separations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum). These are simpler than the MA case and more inherently interesting in my opinion than the "three degrees" result. There are many of them, and I'll leave it to you to pick a favorite.

Answer (score 9):

1. The grandfather, O.G., result by iteration: Martin's Axiom.

   You can include also its more sophisticated offspring, $\sf PFA$ and $\sf MM$ or other forcing axioms, but then you need to start with a supercompact cardinal.
2. Another very interesting result would be the Mitchell proof that assuming a weakly compact cardinal, it is consistent that $\aleph_2$ has the tree property. This is done with a mixed-support of Levy collapses and Cohen reals.
3. And of course, if we are talking about nontrivial supports, then Easton's theorem that assuming $\sf GCH$, any function on regular cardinal satisfying: $F(\kappa)\leq F(\lambda)$ for $\kappa\leq\lambda$, and $\operatorname{cf}(F(\kappa))>\kappa$ is a possible continuum function for regular cardinals.

   (Of course, Easton's original proof is by using a product, but you can also use an iteration. And a product is a kind of iteration, after all...)

Comment: With the exception of possibly MA, I'm not sure these could be called "rudimentary." But they're all good examples.

Comment: True, not very rudimentary, but not very complicated, and quite important, I'd say, to the development of iterated forcing.

Comment: Oh of course (and I upvoted) - I just wanted to clarify for the OP that these are difficult results.

Comment: I think the consistency of $\mathsf{MM}$ is too technical if one is actually going to provide all details.

Comment: @Andrés: MM or MA? Because the MM one was only there as an anecdote. I wouldn't even suggest to include PFA in an undergraduate thesis...

Comment: $\mathsf{MM}$. I read your item 1 as a suggestion to include the arguments for all three of $\mathsf{MA}$, $\mathsf{PFA}$, and $\mathsf{MM}$.

Comment: Oh, no. I meant that MA is the one to be included, PFA and MM are just worth a mention, since the technique is "essentially the same, modulo the difference in the technical complexity of the definitions and the actual details"... :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "you can also use an iteration" for Easton's result? D you mean an infinite iteration instead of (finite) a product? Where can I read this version of the proof? (My understanding is that it is called an interation it is of infinite length and a product if finite.)

Comment: @JPLK: Okay. I think that maybe it would be a good idea for you to learn more about what are products and iterations. Because your understanding is completely wrong.

Comment: @JPLK A finite iteration $\mathbb P*\dot{\mathbb Q}$ involves a poset in the ground model and a poset in the extension. A product $\mathbb P\times\mathbb Q$ involves two posets in the ground model. Finite products can be seen as finite iterations, but in general the poset with $\mathbb P$-name $\dot{\mathbb Q}$ is a genuinely new object. There are differences between the two procedures. For instance, you may want to read about the differences between the product $\mathsf{RAN}_{\omega}\times\mathsf{RAN}_{\omega}$ and the iteration $\mathsf{RAN}_{\omega}*\dot{\mathsf{RAN}_{\omega}}$.

Comment: (@JPLK Here, $\mathsf{RAN}_\omega$ is the poset for adding a random real, as computed in the ground model. So, in the iteration, the second factor is the poset that adds a random real to the extension.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right, I had forgotten some of the terminology, I understand the difference (as explained very clearly in Andres' comment). Can you guide me towards the iteration version of Easton's result? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @JPLK: I think that Jech's big book should have something on that. I think that taking Andrés suggestion on your question and looking at a finite set of cardinals would be a very good first step in this area.

Comment: @JPLK Note that part of my answer (the second paragraph) is all about the difference between iterations and products, even in the finite case.